# Finding strings across lines and replace with nothing

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I have some 'fastq' format DNA sequence files (basically just text files) like this:

```
@Sample_1
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
+
BBBBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EHHHHKKKKKKKKKKKKKKNQQTTTTTT
@
+
@
+
@Sample_4
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
+
BBBBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EHHHHKKKKKKKKKKKKKKNQQTTTTTT
```

My ultimate goal is to turn these into 'fasta' format files, but to do that I need to get rid of the two empty sequences in the middle.

**EDIT**

**The desired output would look like this:**

```
@Sample_1
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
+
BBBBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EHHHHKKKKKKKKKKKKKKNQQTTTTTT
@Sample_4
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
ACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTGACTG
+
BBBBBBBBBBBBEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
EHHHHKKKKKKKKKKKKKKNQQTTTTTT
```

All of the dedicated software I tried (Biopython, stand alone programs, perl scripts posted by others) crash at the empty sequences. This is really just a problem of searching for the string `@\n+` and replacing it with nothing. I googled this and read several posts and tried about a million options with sed and couldn't figure it out. Here are some things that didn't work:

```
sed s/'@'/,/'+'// test.fastq > test.fasta
sed s/'@,+'// test.fastq > test.fasta
```

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I've got a Mac.

Comment: Please post expected output in code tags and let us know on same then.

Comment: `^[+@]+$` with `gm` modifiers. If you need whitespace gone as well `^[+@]+$\s*`

Comment: You can use `grep -Ev '^@[[:blank:]]*$' file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
sed "/^[@+]*$/d" test.fastq > test.fasta
```

The [`/d` option](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-30) tells `sed` to "delete" the matching line (i.e. not print it).

`^` and `$` mean "start of string" and "end of string" respectively, i.e. the line must be an exact match.

So, the above command basically says:

> Print all lines that do *not* only contain `@` or `+`, and write the result to `test.fasta`.

Edit: I misunderstood the question slightly, sorry. If you want to *only* remove pairs of consecutive lines like

```
@
+
```

then you need to perform a multi-line search and replace.

Although this *can* be done with `sed`, it's perhaps easier to use something like a `perl` script instead:

```
perl -0pe 's/^@\n\+\n//gm' test.fastq > test.fasta
```

- The `-0` option turns Perl into "file slurp" mode, where Perl reads the entire input file in one shot (instead of line by line). This enables multi-line search and replace.
- The `-pe` option allows you to run Perl code (pattern matching and replacement in this case) and display output from the command line.
- `^@\n\+\n` is the pattern to match, which we are replacing with nothing (i.e. deleting).
- `/gm` makes the substitution multiline and global.

You could also instead pass `-i` as the first parameter to `perl`, to edit the file inline.

Comment: That's close. The only problem is that I need to keep the other lines that have only a `+` (e.g. the ones in Sample1 and Sample4).

Comment: Please see my edit :) It would have been a little clearer to me if you'd explicitly written the desired contents of `test.fasta` in your question.

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks! Thanks also for the very clear explanation. That helps me learn more so I can hopefully make it work on my own next time. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant solution in the world, but you can use tr to replace the `\n` with a `null` character and back.

```
cat test.fastq | tr '\n' '\0' | sed 's/@\x0+\x0//g' | tr '\0' '\n' > test.fasta
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed '/^@$/{N;/\n+$/d}' file
```

When `@` is found, next line is appended to the pattern space with `N`. 
If `$` is found in next line, the `d` command deletes both lines.